# How select Identifier1 rows related code S and any other combinations

Tags: sql

```
[Identifier1    Identifier2 Identifier3 code
3286    302231  93348   S
3286    311807  95112   S
3434    311620  95042   S
3540    311737  95074   F
3540    311738  95075   F
3553    311750  95085   F
3797    312153  95228   P
3797    312153  95229   P
4076    312506  95415   F
4211    312639  95508   H
4212    312641  95511   H
5316    343278  105219  S
5316    343279  105220  S
6679    368484  108922  T
6716    368538  108953  F
6716    368538  108954  F
7013    405341  121949  S
7013    405342  121950  F
7013    405345  121951  F
7242    405807  122004  S
7242    405807  122005  S
7242    405808  122006  F
```

[image: same as the text]

How to select rows 3286, 3434, 5316, 7013, and 7242 from the above table.
Basically, need to select code 'S' rows for Identifier1 and any other codes that belongs to Identifier1

Comment: What dialect of SQL? MySQL 5.x, MySQL 8.x, Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQLite, etc, etc?

Comment: Please read; [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `EXISTS` operator as the following:

```
SELECT Identifier1, Identifier2, Identifier3, code 
FROM table_name T 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_name D 
             WHERE T.Identifier1 = D.Identifier1 AND D.code='S')
```

Also, you may use `IN` operator with a subquery as the following:

```
SELECT Identifier1, Identifier2, Identifier3, code 
FROM table_name 
WHERE Identifier1 IN (SELECT Identifier1 FROM table_name WHERE code='S')
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/g8a8_qLm) on SQL Server.